# Crank-Nicolson scheme for the Schrödinger equation

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am trying to solve the 1-D Schrödinger equation with the Crank-Nicolson method.
I use the atomic units:

- time < $10^{-14}$ => $413$ a.u.t.
- length $30 \times 10^{-9}$ m => $567$ Bohr radii

---

```
a = 50; 
σ = a/10;
p[x_, 0] := Exp[-(x^2)/(2 σ^2)]; (* граничные условия *)
p[±a, t_] := 0; (* н.у. *)
NN = 100;
h = 1/NN;
repl = x -> ((i*6*a)/NN - 3*a); 

eq = D[Subscript[p, i][t], t] == I/2(Subscript[p, i - 1][t] + 2 Subscript[p, i][t] - 
  Subscript[p, i + 1][t])/h^2(*+D[u[x],x]*Subscript[p,i][t]*)/. repl; 

Table[eq, {i, 0, NN}];
boundary = {Subscript[p, 0][t] == 0, Subscript[p, NN][t] == 0}; 
p0[x_] := Exp[-(x^2)/(2 σ^2)]; 
Cauchy = Table[Subscript[p, i][0] == p0[x] /. repl, {i, 1, NN - 1}]; (*задача Коши*)

eqns = Join[Table[eq, {i, 1, NN - 1}], boundary, Cauchy];
sol = NDSolve[N[eqns], 
N[Table[Subscript[p, i][t], {i, 0, NN}]], {t, 0, 413}];
```

and get this error:

> ```
> NDSolve::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. 
> Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions. >>
> ```

I want to get something like this:

```
sol = NDSolve[{I D[u[t, x], t] == (-1/2)D[u[t, x], {x, 2}], 
     u[0., x] == Exp[-(x^2./(2*σ^2))], u[t, a] == 0, 
     u[t, -a] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 4130}, {x, -a, a}, (*MaxStepSize->0.01,*)
     AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3];

Animate[Plot[Evaluate[Abs[u[t, x] /. First[sol]]^2], {x, -a, a}, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {t, 0, 413}]
```

What's wrong with my code and how to fix it?

Comment: Back in the late 90s I recall Rob Knapp writing an example for CN for Schrodinger. Please search the Wolfram library and I think you should be able to locate it.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I tried to search but can't find Ron Knapp's example, could you search if you have time? I'm very interested in this. But I find [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/785/) example by Terry Robb, which solves the TDSE using a external Fortran subroutine SCHROED. And SCHROED uses a Crank-Nicholson scheme.

Answer (score 8):

Several issues here.

1. Your code isn't an implementation of [Crank–Nicolson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method), but a implementation of method of lines. The way for setting Crank–Nicolson method inside `NDSolve` has been included in [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html#1708771088), in the rest part of this answer I'll simply fix your code.
2. There're several simple mistakes in your code:

(1) The step size is wrong, `h = 1/NN` should be `h = (2 a)/NN`.

(2) The transformation rule is wrong. `repl = x -> ((i*6*a)/NN - 3*a)` should be `repl = x -> (i 2 a)/NN - a`.  BTW, though not quite necessary here, one can make use of `RescalingTransform` to obtain the transform relation like this:

```
    RescalingTransform[{{0, NN}}, {{-a, a}}][{i}]
    (* {-a + (2 a i)/NN} *)
```

(3) The difference formula is wrong. `Subscript[p, i - 1][t] + 2 Subscript[p, i][t] - Subscript[p, i + 1][t]` should be `Subscript[p, i - 1][t] - 2 Subscript[p, i][t] + Subscript[p, i + 1][t]`.

3. The DAE solver of `NDSolve` seems not to be strong enough. The boundary conditions needs to be modified to ODEs, or `NDSolve` will spit out `mconly` warning and fails. This is curtly discussed in [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1306392612), particularly the part about **Boundary Conditions**.

The following is the fixed code:

```
a = 50;
σ = a/10;
p[x_, 0] := Exp[-(x^2/(2 σ^2))];
NN = 100;
h = (2 a)/NN;
repl = x -> (i 2 a)/NN - a;
eq = D[Subscript[p, i][t], t] == 
       (I (Subscript[p, i - 1][t] - 2 Subscript[p, i][t] + 
               Subscript[p, i + 1][t]))/(2 h^2);
boundary = {Subscript[p, 0][t] == 0, Subscript[p, NN][t] == 0};
(* Modify the original b.c.s to almost equivalent ODEs,
   this is also the processing strategy inside NDSolve. *)
diffboundary = With[{sf = 1}, Map[D[#, t] + sf # &, boundary, {2}]];
p0[x_] := Exp[-(x^2/(2 σ^2))];
Cauchy = Table[
  Subscript[p, i][0] == p0[x] /. repl // Evaluate, {i, 0, NN}(*Notice the modification*)]; 
eqns = {Table[eq, {i, 1, NN - 1}], diffboundary, Cauchy};
sollst = NDSolveValue[eqns, Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 0, NN}], {t, 0, 413}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
rebuild = ListInterpolation[
    Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ # // 
     Transpose, {#[[1]]["Coordinates"][[1]], Array[# &, NN + 1, {-a, a}]}] &@sollst

Manipulate[Plot[Abs[rebuild[t, x]]^2, {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {t, 0, 413}]
```

[image]