# NDSolve: how to solve "ndnum error"

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages, boundary-conditions, coding-style

I have a problem of finding the shape of a current. please see  the details here [NDSolve does not accept the boundary condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/297739/96497)

I wrote a code but it gives the "ndnum" error. I tested the recommendation in the document for solving this error but it was not helpful. Also, I tried different values for t0 (initial condition) but still no results.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

```
ClearAll[h, x, n, t]
hx = D[h[x, t], x];
ht = D[h[x, t], t];
n = 1;     (* put  1 for the start, later we will  test different n*)

sqrtTerm = Sqrt[1 + 4*n*Abs[hx]];
pde = Sign[-hx]*1/2*D[h[x, t]*(sqrtTerm - 1), x] == -ht

(*based on 2017 paper Zeng, we decided to put h[x, t0]=1*)
solution = 
NDSolve[{Sign[-hx]*1/2*D[h[x, t]*(sqrtTerm - 1), x] == -ht, 
h[x, 0.001] == 1, h[1, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][h][0, t] == 0}, 
h, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0.001, 10}]
```

Comment: Dear @Alex Trounev , I saw one of your answers to a question here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229198/96497   I am aware that my problem should be solved by the method of line. would you please take a look at my problem and give me some suggestion?

Comment: Could you give a link to the 2017 paper Zeng?

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/prfluids/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevFluids.2.074101  If you do not have access I can send it to you by email

Comment: Thank you. Is it original equation that you proposed or it taken from some paper?

Comment: the formula is original, but it is in the context of Gravity currents.  usually with the help of similarity solutions and scaling the pde is transferred to an ode. but here I need to solve the pde numerically and then compare it with the results of the scaled ode

Comment: @AlexTrounev would you please take a look at this too? hrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://content.wolfram.com/sites/19/2011/12/Fritzson.pdf     page 27 under diffusion problem. I am searching a result with similar profile for the current. a parabolic shape with zero derivative at the left side

Comment: We can solve it with using the Euler wavelets collocation method - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve this problem using the Euler wavelets collocation method and method of lines. Supposed that `h[x,t]` is a real function, we express `Abs[hx]` as `Sqrt[hx^2]`, so we have

```
ClearAll[h, x, n, t]
hx = D[h[x, t], x];
ht = D[h[x, t], t];
n = 1;    

sqrtTerm = Sqrt[1 + 4*n*Sqrt[hx^2]];
pde = Sign[-hx]*1/2*D[h[x, t]*(sqrtTerm - 1), x] == -ht;
```

Nevertheless it can't be solved with `NDSolve` due to some reason. Therefore we use wavelets as a method to discretize the equation on `x`

```
OEm[m_, x_] := 
 Sqrt[2  m + 
    1] Sum[(-1)^(m - k) x^k  Binomial[m, k] Binomial[m + k, k], {k, 0,
     m}]; UE[m_, t_] := OEm[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^((k - 1)/2)  UE[m, 2^(k - 1)  t - n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]; 
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]];
k0 = 2; M0 = 4; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;
wA = Table[wa[i][t], {i, nn}]; wB = Table[wb[i][t], {i, 2}];
w2[x_] := wA . Psi[x]; w1[x_] := wA . int1[x] + wB[[1]];
w0[x_] := wA . int2[x] + wB[[1]]  x + wB[[2]];
eqw = With[{w = 
     w0[x]}, -D[w, t] == (-(1/2))*
      Sign[Derivative[1, 0][h][x, 
        t]]*(Derivative[1, 0][h][x, 
          t]*(-1 + 
           Sqrt[1 + 4*Sqrt[Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]^2]]) + (2*
           h[x, t]*Sign[Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]]*
           Derivative[2, 0][h][x, t])/
         Sqrt[1 + 4*Sqrt[Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]^2]]) /. {h[x, t] ->
       w0[x], Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t] -> w1[x], 
     Derivative[2, 0][h][x, t] -> w2[x]}];
eqnw = Table[eqw, {x, xcol}];
icx = With[{w = w0[x]}, w == 1 /. t -> 10^-3];
ic = Table[icx, {x, xcol}];
bc = With[{w = w0[x]}, 
  Join[{w1[x] == 0} /. x -> 0, {w == 0} /. x -> 1]]; varAll = 
 Join[wA, wB];
icn = Join[ic, bc /. t -> 10^-3]; eqn = Join[eqnw, D[bc, t]]; var1 = 
 D[varAll, t];
{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqn, var1];
f = Inverse[mat // N] . (-vec); vr0 = varAll /. t -> 10^-3;
{v0, mat0} = CoefficientArrays[icn, vr0];
sol0 = LinearSolve[mat0, -v0];
icn0 = Table[vr0[[i]] == sol0[[i]], {i, Length[vr0]}];
sol1 = NDSolve[{Table[var1[[i]] == f[[i]], {i, Length[var1]}], icn0}, 
  varAll, {t, 10^-3, 10}];
```

Visualization

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t, x, w0[x] /. sol1[[1]]}, {t, 10^-3, 10}, {x, 0, 
  1}, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "h"}, 
 Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> {40, 35}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 1, MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1**. This problem can be solved with FDM as follows

```
L = 1;  dx = L/20; xgrid = Range[0, L, dx]; nn = Length[xgrid]; 
M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, DifferenceOrder -> 2]["DifferentiationMatrix"]; 
  M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, DifferenceOrder -> 2]["DifferentiationMatrix"]; 
wA = Table[wa[i][t], {i, nn}]; 
w1 = M1 . wA; w2 = M2 . wA; 
rhs = (-(1/2))*Sign[Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]]*Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]*(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4*Sqrt[Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]^2]]) - 
     (h[x, t]*Derivative[2, 0][h][x, t])/Sqrt[1 + 4*Sqrt[Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]^2]] /. {h[x, t] -> wA, Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t] -> M1 . wA, 
     Derivative[2, 0][h][x, t] -> M2 . wA}; 
eq = Table[D[wA[[i]], t] == -rhs[[i]], {i, 2, nn - 1}]; 
bc = {(M1 . wA)[[1]] == 0, wA[[-1]] == 0}; 
ic = Table[wA[[i]] == 1 /. t -> 10^(-3), {i, 2, nn - 1}]; icn = Join[ic, bc /. t -> 10^(-3)]; 
eqn = Join[eq, D[bc, t]]; var1 = D[wA, t]; 
{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqn, var1]; 
ff = Inverse[N[mat]] . (-vec); vr0 = wA /. t -> 10^(-3); 
{v0, mat0} = CoefficientArrays[icn, vr0]; 
sol0 = LinearSolve[mat0, -v0]; 
icn0 = Table[vr0[[i]] == sol0[[i]], {i, Length[vr0]}]; 

Off[General::partd]; 
f[t_, x_] := Evaluate[ff /. Table[wa[i][t] -> x[[i]], {i, nn}]]

rk2[f_, h_][{t_, x_}] := Module[{k1, k2}, k1 = f[t, x];
   k2 = f[t + h/2, x + h k1/2];
   {t + h, x + h k2}];
 tf = 2; dt = 1/1000; sol = 
 NestList[rk2[f, dt], {0, icn0[[All, 2]]}, Round[tf/dt]];
```

Visualization

```
h = Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{{sol[[j, 1]], xgrid[[i]]}, sol[[j, 2, i]]}, {j, 
     Length[sol]}, {i, nn}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Plot3D[h[t, x], {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "h"}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image: Figure2]

Note, in this example we used the Runge-Kutta second order algorithm on $0\le t \le 2$ with step $10^{-3}$ and difference scheme of second order on $0\le x\le 1$ with step `1/20`.

**Update 2**
This is more advanced code with the Runge-Kutta 4th order algorithm on $0\le t\le 10$ and difference scheme of 4th order on $0\le x\le1$

```
 L = 1; tend = 10; dx = L/20; xgrid = Range[0, L, dx]; nn = Length[xgrid];
M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; M1 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
wA = Table[wa[i][t], {i, nn}];
w1 = M1 . wA; w2 = M2 . wA;

rhs = (-(1/2))*Sign[Derivative[1,0][h][x,t]]*(Derivative[1,0][h][x,t]*(-1+Sqrt[1+4*Sqrt[Derivative[1,0][h][x,t]^2]])+(2*h[x,t]*Sign[Derivative[1,0][h][x,t]]*Derivative[2,0][h][x,t])/Sqrt[1+4*Sqrt[Derivative[1,0][h][x,t]^2]]) /. {h[x, t] -> wA, Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t] -> M1 . wA, 
     Derivative[2, 0][h][x, t] -> M2 . wA}; 

eq = Table[D[wA[[i]], t] == -rhs[[i]], {i, 2, nn - 1}];
bc = {(M1 . wA)[[1]] == 0, wA[[-1]] == 0};
ic = Table[wA[[i]] == 1 /. t -> 10^-3, {i, 2, nn - 1}]; icn = 
 Join[ic, bc /. t -> 10^-3];
eqn = Join[eq, D[bc, t]]; var1 = D[wA, t];
{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqn, var1];
ff = Inverse[mat // N] . (-vec); vr0 = wA /. t -> 10^-3;
{v0, mat0} = CoefficientArrays[icn, vr0];
sol0 = LinearSolve[mat0, -v0];
icn0 = Table[vr0[[i]] == sol0[[i]], {i, Length[vr0]}];

Off[General::partd]; 
f[t_, x_] := Evaluate[ff /. Table[wa[i][t] -> x[[i]], {i, nn}]]

rk4[f_, h_][{t_, y_}] := Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4}, k1 = f[t, y];
  k2 = f[t + h/2, y + h k1/2];
  k3 = f[t + h/2, y + h k2/2];
  k4 = f[t + h, y + h k3];
  {t + h, y + h/6*(k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4)}]
```

Example of usage

```
dt1 = 1/1000; tf = 10; sol1 = 
 NestList[rk4[f, dt1], {0, icn0[[All, 2]]}, Round[tf/dt1]];
```

Visualization

```
h = Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{{sol1[[j, 1]], xgrid[[i]]}, sol1[[j, 2, i]]}, {j, 
     Length[sol1]}, {i, nn}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> 8];
Plot[Table[h[t, x], {t, {.1, .5, 1, 2, 5, 10}}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 
  1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "H"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"t =", t}], {t, {.1, .5, 1, 2, 5, 10}}]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: This is amazing. thank you very much. I appreciate it.  it will takes time for me to understand it as I am new in Mathematica. But just one question, As I had no idea about Euler wavelet method ,I searched a little bit and only found that its applicable in wave and signal problems. my formula is for the fluid propagates into a porous medium. what is the logic to use this method for such  a problem? it would be grate if you explain a bit more.

Comment: @AWer This kind of wavelets nothing to do with signal process. This is the system of orthogonal functions to implement the decomposition of solution.  In this example we use only 10 collocation points to compute numerical solution. We can compare it with other methods like FEM an FDM.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much. it is great. Would you please guide me how to get the 2d plot of the results? I need to have the profile of the current. H vs x plot that shows the evolution of the current in different times

Comment: @AWer Could you specified the different times like for example  `times={0,1,2,3,4}`?

Comment: yes. I want to see the profile at t= [ 0.001, 1, 10]

Comment: At t=0.001 we have initial condition. So you need to compute profile at t={1,10}?

Comment: ok. so lets considered  t= [1,5,10]

Comment: @AWer Please, see Update 2 to my answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks a milion

Comment: Dear @Alex Trounev, would you please tell me how it is possible to solve this equation in an infinite domain?

Comment: @AWer Do you mean infinite in space or in time?

Comment: I mean infinite space

Comment: @AWer In numerical methods it depends on what we treat as infinity in this problem, for example, we can solve on $0\le x \le 100$.

Comment: Dear @Alex Trounev, I think  I did not explain my problem well. I wanted to solve the problem in the semi-infinite domain where x is bounded from zero and goes to + infinity. In this way, the height of the current  becomes smaller and smaller  but not zero

Comment: I searched and I found a problem solved with Crank-Nikelson method. but I don't know how to imply it in this code . would you please see these examples? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38743/crank-nicolson-scheme-for-the-schr%c3%b6dinger-equation/300085#300085

Comment: also this one : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278011/pde-involving-derivative-at-boundary-with-a-boundary-condition-at-infinity